# bootstrap 4 nav-tabs stop border-bottom from jumping down on hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I've tried to incorporate my own style to the nav-tabs in bootstrap 4 because the out-of-the-box does fit my theme very well.

I've got it looking how I want it to, but when I hover over a tab, the border-bottom on the nav-tabs section moves down about 1px. I've tried manipulating the margin, padding, etc but can't seem to figure out how to get it to stop doing it.

Can someone help here?

```
<div class="container-fluid body-content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-lg-2">
      <div class="row m-b-2">
        <div class="col-xs-12">

          <div class="row m-b-2 left-nav-container">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="row left-nav"><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 left-nav-menu-item" href="#">Update Starters</a>
                <a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 left-nav-menu-item hidden-xs" href="/rankings/all">Wrestler Rankings</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-lg-10">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <!-- Nav tabs -->
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#roster" role="tab">Roster</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#schedule" role="tab">Schedule</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#elig" role="tab">Eligibility Breakdown</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#depth" role="tab">Depth Chart</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#info" role="tab">Team Info</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <!-- Tab panes -->
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="roster" role="tabpanel">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-heading">
                  <h2>Roster</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Weight</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Class</th>
                        <th>Record</th>
                        <th>Starter</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr style="background-color: lightgray;">
                        <td>125</td>
                        <td><a href="/wrestler/profile/12221/dancejoey">#4 Dance, Joey</a></td>
                        <td>JR</td>
                        <td>29 - 3</td>
                        <td>
                          <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Starter field is required." disabled="disabled" id="Wrestlers_0__Starter" name="Wrestlers[0].Starter" style="font-size: large; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px;"
                          type="checkbox" value="true" />
                          <input name="Wrestlers[0].Starter" type="hidden" value="false" />
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="schedule" role="tabpanel">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-heading">
                  <h2>Schedule</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Opponent</th>
                        <th>Comparison</th>
                        <th>Win</th>
                        <th>Score</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>11/07/15</td>
                        <td>Iowa State - Virginia Tech Dual</td>

                        <td>Dual</td>
                        <td>
                          <a href="/team/main/35/iowa-state">#19 Iowa State</a>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                          <a href="/team/dualcomparison/74/virginia-tech/35/iowa-state">Dual Comparison</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>W</td>
                        <td>
                          <a href="/schedule/boxscore/4787/iowa-state-virginia-tech-dual">32 - 3</a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>11/08/15</td>
                        <td>
                          <a href="/schedule/tournamentparticipants/4876">Hokie Open</a>
                        </td>

                        <td>Tournament</td>
                        <td>Hokie Open</td>

                        <td>(NA)</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="elig" role="tabpanel">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-heading">
                  <h2>Eligibility Breakdown</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table class="table table-sm table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th class="text-xs-center elig-header-border">Weight</th>
                        <th class="text-xs-center elig-header-border">Recruit</th>
                        <th class="text-xs-center elig-header-border">True Freshman</th>
                        <th class="text-xs-center elig-header-border">Redshirt Freshman</th>
                        <th class="text-xs-center elig-header-border">Sophomore</th>
                        <th class="text-xs-center elig-header-border">Junior</th>
                        <th class="text-xs-center elig-header-border">Senior</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="text-xs-center elig-header-border">125</td>
                        <td class="text-xs-center elig-cell">
                          <p>Joey Prata</p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-xs-center elig-cell">
                          <p><a href="/wrestler/profile/40361/haskett-ryan">#70 Ryan Haskett</a></p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-xs-center elig-cell">
                          <p></p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-xs-center elig-cell">
                          <p></p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-xs-center elig-cell">
                          <p><a href="/wrestler/profile/12221/dance-joey">#4 Joey Dance</a></p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-xs-center elig-cell">
                          <p></p>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="depth" role="tabpanel">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-heading">
                      <h2>Depth Chart</h2>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-heading">
                      <h3 class="text-xs-center">125</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                      <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Class</th>
                            <th>Record</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td><a href="/wrestler/profile/12221/dance-joey">#4 Dance Joey</a></td>
                            <td>JR</td>
                            <td class="text-xs-right">29 - 3</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td><a href="/wrestler/profile/40361/haskett-ryan">#70 Haskett Ryan</a></td>
                            <td>FR</td>
                            <td class="text-xs-right">4 - 5</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="info" role="tabpanel">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-heading">
                  <h2>Team Information</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="card-block">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="Edit">
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The SchoolId field is required." id="SchoolInfo_SchoolId" name="SchoolInfo.SchoolId" type="hidden" value="74" />

                    <div class="row form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                        <label class="form-control-label" for="SchoolInfo_SchoolName">SchoolName</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-4">
                        <input class="form-control" id="SchoolInfo_SchoolName" name="SchoolInfo.SchoolName" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="Virginia Tech" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                        <label class="form-control-label" for="SchoolInfo_Aka">Aka</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-4">
                        <input class="form-control" id="SchoolInfo_Aka" name="SchoolInfo.Aka" placeholder="(ie North Dakota State University is NDSU)" type="text" value="" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                        <label class="form-control-label" for="SchoolInfo_Nickname">Nickname</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-4">
                        <input class="form-control" id="SchoolInfo_Nickname" name="SchoolInfo.Nickname" type="text" value="Hokies" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                        <label class="form-control-label" for="SchoolInfo_Division">Division</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-4">
                        <input class="form-control" id="SchoolInfo_Division" name="SchoolInfo.Division" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="Division I" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                        <label class="form-control-label" for="SchoolInfo_Conference">Conference</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-4">
                        <input class="form-control" id="SchoolInfo_Conference" name="SchoolInfo.Conference" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="ACC" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                        <label class="form-control-label" for="SchoolInfo_TwitterHandle">TwitterHandle</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-4">
                        <input class="form-control" id="SchoolInfo_TwitterHandle" name="SchoolInfo.TwitterHandle" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="@VT_Wrestling" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true">
                          <ul>
                            <li style="display:none"></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="hidden-xs-down">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-dark bg-inverse p-t-1 text-xs-center">
      <h6>&copy; 2016 - WrestleStat - ACS, LLC</h6>
    </nav>
  </footer>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}


/* Wrapping element */


/* Set some basic padding to keep content from hitting the edges */

.body-content {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}


/* Set widths on the form inputs since otherwise they're 100% wide */

input,
select,
textarea {
  max-width: 280px;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}


/* Carousel */

.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10 !important;
}

.carousel-caption p {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-caption {
    z-index: 10 !important;
  }
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  /*bottom: 0;*/
  width: 99%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: black;
  /* #f5f5f5; */
}

.widget {
  font-size: .85rem;
  padding: .75rem .75rem;
}

.widget-header {
  padding: 1rem .75rem .5rem .75rem;
}

.borderless td,
.borderless th {
  border: none;
}

.no-underline {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*.card-block-border-bottom {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}*/


/* Left Nav stuff */

.left-nav-menu-item {
  color: #eceeef;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top: .1rem solid white;
  background-color: #373a3c;
}

.left-nav {
  line-height: 3rem;
}

.left-nav > div:first-of-type {
  margin-top: .2rem;
}

a.left-nav-menu-item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.left-nav-menu-item:hover {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* End of left nav */


/* Top nav overrides since Bootstrap 4 isn't complete */

.navbar-brand {
  float: none;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item {
  float: none;
}

.navbar-divider,
.navbar-nav .nav-item + .nav-item,
.navbar-nav .nav-link + .nav-link {
  margin-left: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 34em) {
  .navbar-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .navbar-nav .nav-item {
    float: left;
  }
  .navbar-divider,
  .navbar-nav .nav-item + .nav-item,
  .navbar-nav .nav-link + .nav-link {
    margin-left: 1rem;
  }
}

.nav.navbar-nav {
  padding-top: .3rem;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link.donate {
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: green;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link.donate:hover {
  color: white;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item .dropdown-item {
  background-color: #373a3c;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eceeef;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item .dropdown-item:hover {
  color: #eceeef;
}


/* End of top nav overrides */


/* tab overrides */

.nav.nav-tabs .nav-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav.nav-tabs a.active {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #373a3c;
  border-bottom: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav.nav-tabs li.nav-item:hover {
  border: 1px solid #373a3c;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: none;
}

.nav.nav-tabs li.nav-item:hover a {
  color: black;
}

ul.nav.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #373a3c;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

ul.nav.nav-tabs div.tab-content div.card {
  border: none;
}


/* end of tab overrides*/


/* eligibility breakdown page */

.elig-header-border {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.elig-border {
  border: .1rem solid black;
}

td.elig-cell:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

td.elig-cell:hover a:hover {
  color: white;
}


/* end of eligibility breakdown */
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3b4pL5ed/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## How to debug hover states

In order to see what happens when hovering an element, I recommend you to use the "force element state" functionality `:hover` of [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools):

[image]

Doing that, I can play editing and checking/uncheking stuff to find a solution, then elaborate a CSS correction.

## Solution

There's no doubt you have a problem with nested borders. You can use the previous technique to find a cleaner solution, but here is a fast fix:

```
.nav.nav-tabs li.nav-item {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin-bottom: -2px !important;
}

.nav.nav-tabs li.nav-item:hover {
  border: 1px solid #373a3c !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent !important;
}

.nav.nav-tabs li.nav-item a.nav-link:hover {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3b4pL5ed/6/)

## Edit

Considering the `:focus` event, which is triggered when the element gets clicked, you may want to override the default Bootstrap styles for it too.

Add the focus selector `.nav.nav-tabs a.active:focus` to these styles, so they apply when focusing the element too:

```
.nav.nav-tabs a.active, .nav.nav-tabs a.active:focus {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #373a3c;
  border-bottom: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Next to it, you'll want to override the background to keep it white when hovering, even when the element is also focused, so add this:

```
.nav.nav-tabs a.active:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3b4pL5ed/7/)

Comment: Thanks, had no idea about the forced state thing in Chrome. Regarding your comment about "nested borders", I'm also assuming that's the issue with my cards not formatting correctly when they are inside nav-tabs...but that's a whole new question.

Comment: Any idea why, when you click on a tab, the background color doesn't switch to black? (which was an override that I placed on the .active class)? It DOES switch to black if you click in the css section on jsfiddle. On the actual deployed website, it never switches the background to black.

Comment: When an element is clicked, it gains the `:focus` event. Bootstrap has default styles for `.nav-link.active:focus` that you must override if you want to keep that style as well. I'm editing the answer.

Comment: Done. When using a CSS framework like Bootstrap, it is not trivial to edit the look of some of its elements. As you can see, you need to override plenty styles coming from different states of elements. Depending on the required customization, you may consider to use an existing theme for Bootstrap that fits better your needs and doesn't force you to edit so many styles.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution if you don’t want to add a transparent border but just using padding

Change your the entry .nav.nav-tabs li.nav-item:hover to:

```
.nav.nav-tabs li.nav-item:hover {
    border: 1px solid #373a3c;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
```

and add:

```
.nav.nav-tabs li.nav-item{
  padding: 1px 1px 0px 1px;
}
```

It should work as expected. [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fooffjje)

Comment: Nope, border still jumps down

Comment: It is working fine to me (tested in chrome and FF) https://jsfiddle.net/fooffjje/

Comment: I tested it on the fiddle that I provided in the question. Update the fiddle and post it here...

Comment: @ganders can you post the link of jsfiddle you changed including my code and can you confirm the result of checking the jsfiddle I posted jsfiddle.net/fooffjje ?

Comment: K, I just checked your fiddle (didn't see that you originally attached it) and it's working. I just took my fiddle, and added those two sections and it didn't work for mine. Maybe I missed something on the copy/paste. Please edit your answer so I'm allowed to change my vote.

Comment: Thank you ganders. Yes you need to change the first block of code ".nav.nav-tabs li.nav-item:hover" (remove the existing one if you are adding the new one) and then and the second block ".nav.nav-tabs li.nav-item". I just edited my answer as well to add the link to JSFiddle